# Can you replicate Optics Compensation in VSE?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, image, effects

The Effect "*Optics Compensation*" in **After Effects** is great to compensate the distortion of certain lenses such as Fisheye lenses or wide angle, etc.

[image]

I have only so far been able to replicate this in Blender by assigning my photo/video to a plane in the 3D space, aiming the Camera down and using Compositor nodes as such:

[image]

[image]

But for efficiency purposes - because assigning videos of photo textures to a plane adds an extra step, I would like to be able to use this Lens Distortion to the VSE directly.

I have seen some questions here saying you can link the **Compositor** to a scene, but I am unable to reproduce and to fully use the Compositor's nodes in video edits, ideally I would like to see the change in effects settings live.

[image]

**How can the Compositor Node effects be used in VSE in a streamlined way?**

Comment: Are you talking manually entering the distortion or using calculated distortion data from the camera tracker? As in- I know the camera tracker can un-distort / re-distort footage, and I'm pretty sure this is done in the compositor.

Comment: I want to use the lens distortion (and other) node in the video editor as simply as possible

Comment: Sorry then, I shall have to duck-out of this: I know little or nothing about the video editor,  compositor & tracker in Blender- as I use Davinci, Fusion & Syntheyes for these workflows myself... Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can directly undistort **footage** in the Sequencer, once you have it set up correctly in 2.8.

Open up the **movie clip editor** and open your footage.

[image: footage]

To properly choose some distorsion value, we will have to be able to preview the result. Go to the top right of the movie clip editor, click on *Clip Display* and check **Render Undistorted**. This will give us the undistorted view of the footage live in the movie clip editor.

[image: render undistort]

Open the **Track** rider <kbd>N</kbd> > *Track* and go to the **Lens** Panel. Here are the Lens Distorsion parameters K1, K2 and K3. Change their values and see how the footage (un)distorts itself. It can help to draw a Line *Annotation* to evaluate the straightness of lines.

[image: track]

Once you are satisfied with the undistorsion go to the sequencer. (You will have to load up all the footages in the movie clip editor which you want to use in the sequencer if you want to undistort them there.)

Add the created movie clip to the sequencer by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Clip* > *YourClipName.mov*.
Open up the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> and go to the *Strip* rider. Go to the *Adjust > Video* panel and check **Undistort Clip**. The added clip will be rendered undistorted directly from the sequencer.

[image: render undistorted]

Answer (score 4):

There's currently no effect strip (that I know of) that directly allows optic compensation on a clip as simply as it does in After Effects (that would be a good vse coding project to work on). But you can use compositing nodes **in a separate scene** for a clip and then add that scene to the VSE in your original scene.
(Note that you don't need to use a plane to achieve this, you can add the movie clip directly into the compositor)

[image]